# Mongo query if field does not exist. If exists, must be within a range

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection that has an endDateTime field:

If `endDateTime` is `null`, the operation is not yet finished.
If it has finished, `endDateTime` contains the timestamp (Javascript `Date.now()`)

How can I query for records that is not yet finished (`endDateTime` is `null`) or has ended in the last 24 hours:

```
   let endDateTime = Date.now();
   let startDateTime = endDateTime - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

   query.endDateTime = {
             $or: [
                   null,
                   { $and: [{ $gte: startDateTime }, { $lte: endDateTime }] }
                  ]
    };
```

My query is returning registers before `24 hours ago`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your criteria with `$or`:

```
db.col.find({
    $or: [
        { endDateTime: null },
        { endDateTime: { $gt: Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } } 
    ]
})
```

or if you have no `endDateTime` key in some of your documents then you need [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
db.col.find({
    $or: [
        { endDateTime: { $exists: false } },
        { endDateTime: { $gt: Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } } 
    ]
})
```

Comment: What about the startDateTime parameter?

Comment: @Mendes the question is if you really need it ? That would mean that you have some dates from the future